# Best architecture for setting up multiple apache on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, webserver, elastic-load-balancer

We are migrating our web app to AWS and our current architecture  involves apache server making one to one connection to jboss EAP instance.

How do i architect this setup on AWS

I am planning to put an LB in front of apache and another LB in front of JBOSS eap instances.
How does auto scaling work? since each apache server makes one to one connection with the Jboss instance, when a new instance of apache EC2 instance is spun up, a corresponding Jboss EC2 instance needs to be spun up as well. How do i accomplish that?

I am sure there is a better alternative to the above.

Comment: Why place a LB between Apache and Jboss? If you want a 1:1 relationship then the LB would break that. Typically you would run one instance of Apache and Jboss on the same server, and put a load balancer in front of a pool of those servers.

Comment: we are planning to keep apache in DMZ for security reasons. One to one mapping may not help when we auto scale since the ip address needs to be hardcoded in  apache config right

Comment: On AWS you can just put the Load Balancer in the DMZ (i.e. make it public) and keep access to everything else locked down inside your VPC. Not sure what you mean by hard-coding the ip address in Apache, do you mean the IP address to Jboss? Again, trying to scale two groups of servers that need a 1:1 mapping with each other is going to be extremely painful on AWS. Just keep Apache and Jboss on the same server.